# Список провайдеров выделенных серверов/хостинга/VPS

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер, хостинг, провайдер

Подскажите пожалуйста каких провайдеров VPS/выделенных серверов/Веб хостинга вы знаете, укажите их плюсы/минусы, в каких странах доступны сервера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## VPS

### [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com)

**Страна:** Америка
**Расположение серверов:** США, Нидерланды, Сингапур, Англия, Франция, Германия, Канада, Индия
**Плюсы:**

> 1. Удобная администраторская панель
> 2. Создание проекта и прикрепление к нему нескольких серверов

**Минусы:**

> 1. Если работаете с Российскими серверами, то из-за блокировок Телеграм, многие запросы с вашего сервера могут недоходить до российских серверов.
> 2. Дорогая цена

---

## Выделенный сервер

### [Kimsufi](https://www.kimsufi.com/)

**Страна:** Франция
**Расположение серверов:** Франция, Канада
**Плюсы:**

> 1. Легкая регистрация и покупка сервера
> 2. АнтиDDoS защита от OVH!
> 3. Огромный выбор серверов
> 4. Дешево

**Минусы:**

> 1. Не обнаружено

---

## Web Hosting