# Хостинг для бота ВК PHP

Tags: php, веб-программирование, хостинг, бот

Какой хостинг лучше подойдёт для бота группы ВКонтакте на PHP?
Heroku или любой другой бесплатный хостинг (типа 000webhost или zzz.com.ua)? Почему то тыкают пальцем на Heroku, хотя там сервер уходит в сон спустя 30 минут бездействия и потом ему нужно время, чтобы проснуться. А на 000webhost бывает такое, что при переходе на страницу сайта, пишет "No such website", хотя эта страница существует...

Comment: Купить VDS и не париться

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего купить себе VPS (Virtual Private Server) или Dedicated Server (выделенный сервер).

Вот [в этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078534/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-vps) есть примеры таких серверов